# Skip a after hook in a Cypress test

Tags: cypress

In my Cypress config I have a hook:

```js
//hooks.ts

after(() => {
    if (Cypress.currentTest.titlePath[0] === 'Skip after') {
        return;
    }
    cy.wait(2500);
    cy.el('btnLogoutUser').should('exist').click({ force: true });
    cy.url().should('contain', 'login');
    cy.task('getCompany').then((data: any) => {
        cy.task('cleanCompany', data.company.company_id).then((response: any) => {
            cy.log(`
=================================================
Removed company with id: ${response.substring(47)}
=================================================
            `);
        });
    });
    localStorage.clear();
});
```

But on some tests I want to skip this hook. That's why I added the if condition.

```js
//test.cy.ts

describe('Skip after', () => {
    it('Does something', () => {
        cy.el('btnCompanySettings').click({ force: true });
    });
});
```

This works, but I would much rather add a boolean value in the describe and pass that so I can check that value. Something like:

```js
//test.cy.ts

describe({title: 'Name of test', skipAfter: true}), () => { ... }
```

But the describe only takes a string value.

Comment: IMO don't try to be too clever - just add cleanup code to Custom Command and call when needed.

Comment: I need to clean up after each test except when I'm developing a test.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom property to the configuration object in your `describe` method (that is the one between the suite name and the callback function). Then, you can access it from `Cypress.config()`.

```js
describe("Suite", { skipAfter: false }, () => {
  it("test", () => {
    //your code
  });

  after(() => {
    if (Cypress.config().skipAfter) {
      return;
    }
    //your code
  });
});
```

Comment: This does not work and gives this error:  ||  (property) skipAfter: boolean
Argument of type '{ skipAfter: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TestConfigOverrides'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'skipAfter' does not exist in type 'TestConfigOverrides'.ts(2345) ||